# How to get from database list instead of list of lists?

Tags: database, dart

I have columns with regions. I need get all unique values to List.

The follow function return List of Lists:

```
getListOfRegionsFromDB() async {
   String sql_get_regions = """SELECT DISTINCT(region) FROM "public"."ftp_files"; """;
   List<dynamic> result = await connection.query(sql_get_regions);
   print(result);

}
```

And I am getting result like:

```
[[Tverskaja_obl], [Belgorodskaja_obl], [Uljanovskaja_obl], [Jaroslavskaja_obl]]
```

But I want to:

```
["Tverskaja_obl", "Belgorodskaja_obl", "Uljanovskaja_obl", "Jaroslavskaja_obl"]
```

Is there any short way to do it? I see only one way -- to iterate throw data with for loop.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: If what you have is a `List<List<String>>` you can use the expand method: `result.expand((e) => e)`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?